# same php file to serve 3 domains

Tags: php, url-routing

I'm rather new to php and wonder if the following technically feasible?

I would like to have 3 urls to hit the same page on the server, but display different slightly content (content text is in stored in database tables with a indicator flag whether the content belongs to urlA or urlB), i.e.

URL_A will show content specific to A's products only, URL_B will show content specific to B's products only, URL_C will show products for both A and B. All these URLs will point to the same page (index.php) and I would prefer if the domains all remain as they are entered to differentiate the branding and content, rather than using 301 to redirect 2 of the domains (e.g. a visitor entering www.urlA.com will be able to continue browsing/navigating the website pages like www.urlA.com/about-us or www.urlA.com/news)

Can this be implemented using a mod-rewrite and some php logic or passing some session or hidden form input to various pages? Any advice on where/how to start would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$_SERVER['HOST_NAME']` to determine which virtual host is being accessed.  Use this value to perform whatever logic you require.